# Input Range Error on View - MVC 4 C#

Tags: c#, validation

I'm having a little bit of trouble with this, I have a range input for a math exercise, i have a Model like this:

```
public class Percentage
{
    public String num { get; set; }

    public String percentage { get; set; }

    public String val { get; set; }
}
```

So, i send the values from the controller to the view, but every time i tried to send the form this message pop up:

[Range Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPLBa.png)

And in my view i have something like this:

```
@model Algoritmos.Models.Operations

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "exercise", @class = "form-exercises", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="main-section">
        <h1>Porcentajes</h1>
        <p>¿Cuánto es el @Model.per.percentage% de @Model.per.num?:</p>
        <div class="percentage-simple">
            <div class="range">
                @if (Model.per.val != null)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.per.val, new { @type="range", @min="0", @max= (@Model.per.num).ToString() })
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="range" name="per.val" min="0" max=@Model.per.num.ToString() />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="errors-section">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        @if (@ViewBag.Respuesta != null)
        {
            @ViewBag.Respuesta
        }
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.per.num)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.per.percentage)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.operation)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.count)
    <div class="send-section">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Continuar" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.main-section input[type=range]').on('change mousemove', function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
        })
    })    
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the message 'Please enter a value between x and y?'

Comment: That's the weird thing, i don't have any validation for it but still i'm getting that message.

Comment: How about in the controller where the @Viewbag is loaded for Respuesta?

Comment: Yeah, i thought about that so i take it off from the page and still the same, apparently it was because unobtrusive.js, without that it works.